# программная разметка

Tags: android

Есть метод ,при нажатии на кнопку должна появится программно созданная разметка ,но ничего не появляется ,в чем проблема?

```
 public void Load(){
    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

    LinearLayout parentLinear = new LinearLayout(this);
    parentLinear.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 160, Gravity.BOTTOM));
    parentLinear.setWeightSum(1f);
    parentLinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    LinearLayout linearLayoutLeft = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayoutLeft.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.5f));
    linearLayoutLeft.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayoutLeft.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    LinearLayout linearLayoutRight = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayoutRight.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.5f));
    linearLayoutRight.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayoutRight.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    parentLinear.addView(linearLayoutLeft);
    parentLinear.addView(linearLayoutRight);
    frameLayout.addView(parentLinear);
    RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
    rel.addView(frameLayout);
}
```

Comment: Ноль первым параметром в конструкторе -- из каких соображений?

Comment: @post_zeew не знаю я не очень пока разбираюсь в программной разметке активити ,мне помогли здесь сделать